# Setting environment variables for Fortran XE Composer 2013 SP1.2.144 compiler for 64b

Tags: intel-fortran, intel-composer

I've successfully installed l_fcompxe_2013_sp1.2.144 for my Linux ubuntu 64 bits i5.
To setup environment variables I've changed to root and run

```
    ./compilervars.sh intel64
    ./compilervars_arch.sh intel64
```

located in folder /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.2.144/bin

after that, I've tried this

```
    ifort --help
```

but message says **ifort: command not found**
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: *I've changed to root and run* suggests that root's version of the environment variables may have been established.  As what user did you try  `ifort --help` ?

Comment: I've tried that as root. Environment variables settled as root must work for user and super user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you source the script.  I couldn't tell from your question whether you had sourced or just executed the script

you should do:

source    PATH-TO-INSTALLATION/bin/compilervars.sh intel64

(same as):

.    PATH-TO-INSTALLATION/bin/compilervars.sh intel64